# Why is a matrix multiplied by its adjugate is diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm referring to the formula $A\operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)I=C$. I understand why we get the determinants on the diagonal, but why does every $c_{ij}$ with $i\neq j$ is zero? I don't seem to get it intuitively and all the proofs I have seen treat it like it is obvious.

Comment: Look for the expression $det(A)*I$. Isn't I the identity matrix? That's why every non-diagonal entry is zero

Comment: The question is: 'why is $A \ \text{adj}(A) = \text{det}(A) I$?'. The OP understands why $A \ \text{adj}(A)$ has $\text{det}(A)$'s on the diagonal, but not why it has $0$'s everywhere else.

Comment: That's the theorem of Laplace on row or column expansions, written in matrix form. The fact that $c_{ij}=0$ for $i\ne j$ is sometimes called "expansion with respect to the wrong row" or "alien cofactor".

Comment: Start from A^-1=1/det(A)* adj(A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the matrix $A$, for two distinct indices $i,i'$ replace row $i'$ by row $i$ leaving all other rows the same, including row $i.$ Call the new matrix $B.$ Note that B has  two idenical rows. Note that along row $i'$, the matrices $A$ and $B$ have the same co-factors. Expand $\det B$ along row $i'$. Since $B$ has two identical rows, its determinant is 0. The elements of $B$ along row $i'$ are the elements of $A$ along row $i$ and the co-factors of $B$ along row $i'$ are the co-factors of $A$ along row $i'$.